# Focus the text field as soon as it becomes visible when the page opens

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to make the input field immediately active when entering the page, automatically focusing on the TextField and immediately opening the keyboard? I added the `autofocus: true` method to the TextField but it doesn't help, you still need to click on the input field when the page opens.

**widget**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
          onPressed: () {
            _onBackPressed(context);
          },
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
            constants.Assets.arrowLeft,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 14,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 14),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
              color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
            ),
            child: TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              onChanged: onChanged,
              style: constants.Styles.textFieldTextStyleWhite,
              cursorColor: Colors.white,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10,
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                prefixIcon: Container(
                  width: 10,
                  height: 10,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    constants.Assets.search,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

to make your textfield autofocus when the page is open
you need to initial `FocusNode` and call `requestFocus()`
here example:

```html
class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
  late FocusNode _focusNode;
  late TextEditingController _controller;
  
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: TextField(
            controller:_controller,
            focusNode:_focusNode
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

hope this answer your question

Answer (score 1):

this code can focus, they are almost same to yours.Probably (I am not sure but) your widget trees prevent to focus somewhere.. ---> https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus check this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Material(
        child: TestPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => TestPageState();
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  late final FocusNode focusNode;
  @override
  void initState() {
    focusNode = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          onChanged: (String ada) {},
          cursorColor: Colors.white,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 10,
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none,
            prefixIcon: Container(
              width: 10,
              height: 10,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't understand what it is, because I don't seem to use anything special.

Comment: Probably a widget prevent to auto focus, reading flutter documents will solve problems like these.